# Halogens chemical reactions with each other

Tags: halogenation, halogens

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halogen

Can Halogens react with each other?

Examples :

Chlorine + Flourine

Flourine + Iodine

Iodine + Bromine

Chlorine + Bromine

and so on.

Permutations and Combinations.

Chlorine + Flourine =

Chlorine + Bromine =

Chlorine + Iodine =

Flourine + Bromine =

Flourine + Iodine =

Bromine + Iodine =

What will be the chemical reactions & applications?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interhalogen

Answer (score 2):

There is plenty of information about all these compounds if you look at "Interhalogen compounds" through Google. All these compounds are known :

AX- type : ClF, BrF, BrCl, ICl, IBr

AX3-type: ClF3, BrF3, (ICl3)2,

AX5-type: ClF5, BrF5, IF5,

AX7-type: IF7.

Their synthesis, structures and properties are nicely described, much better than what I could do here.

And please note that the symbol F describes the element **fluorine**, and not **flourine**. Its compounds are **fluorides**, and not **flourides**.